# ipywidgets tab not rendering in jupyter lab notebook

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

Altough I've seen many posts regarding confusion on ipwidgets and jupyter labs, most of these seem to be related to virtual environments, earlier versions of nb or jl, or earlier install routines of ipwidgets.  although I'm running my notebook from a directory below where a virtual environment has been activated, I have not activated it and do no think I'm running in a virtual env.

although my sliders and other widgets render correctly, my tabs do not.

simple code pasted directly from examples in [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#tabs):

```
import ipywidgets as widgets 
tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'] 
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents] 
tab = widgets.Tab() tab.children = children 
tab.titles = [str(i) for i in range(len(children))] 
tab
```

[image: incorrectly formed tabs view]

Note how the tabs are not formed.  The tab descriptions are there and work but aren’t spread acrosss the top.

I have tried:

1. Updating jupyter lab and ipywidgets
2. Have tried to shut down computer and notebook
3. Manually activated extension as follows:

   ```
    PS C:\Users\lee\PycharmProjects\htmlsandbox\wsj_econ> jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
    Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
          - Validating: ok
   ```

   running Jupyter lab Version 4.0.2

   ** Update -- as I was shutting down the server, I looked at the logs and am seeing errors that I'm not sure how to handle:

> [IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered:
> jupyter.widget.control [IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:
> b4acacde-dc4d-4362-8768-8dad75ac0bba [W 2023-06-21 18:24:05.684
> ServerApp] Got events for closed stream
> <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x0000024A7BC79B40> [W
> 2023-06-21 18:24:05.684 ServerApp] Got events for closed stream
> <zmq.eventloop.zmqstream.ZMQStream object at 0x0000024A7BE06260> [E
> 2023-06-21 18:24:09.215 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET
> /lab/api/extensions?query&page=1&per_page=30&refresh=0&1687386245224
> (::1)
> HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET',
> uri='/lab/api/extensions?query&page=1&per_page=30&refresh=0&1687386245224',
> version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1')
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py",
> line 1713, in _execute
> result = await result
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\extension_manager_handler.py",
> line 37, in get
> extensions, last_page = await self.manager.list_extensions(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 368, in list_extensions
> await self.refresh(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 402, in refresh
> await self._update_extensions_list(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 575, in _update_extensions_list
> extensions, last_page = await self.list_packages(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py",
> line 214, in list_packages
> data = await self.*fetch_package_metadata(name, latest_version, self.base_url)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\async_lru_*init**.py",
> line 218, in **call**
> return await asyncio.shield(fut)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py",
> line 36, in _fetch_package_metadata
> response = await http_client.fetch(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\simple_httpclient.py",
> line 340, in run
> stream = await self.tcp_client.connect(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py",
> line 288, in connect
> stream = await stream.start_tls(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py",
> line 1389, in _do_ssl_handshake
> self.socket.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1342, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [W 2023-06-21 18:24:09.253
> ServerApp] wrote error: 'Unhandled error'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py",
> line 1713, in _execute
> result = await result
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\extension_manager_handler.py",
> line 37, in get
> extensions, last_page = await self.manager.list_extensions(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 368, in list_extensions
> await self.refresh(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 402, in refresh
> await self._update_extensions_list(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py",
> line 575, in _update_extensions_list
> extensions, last_page = await self.list_packages(query, page, per_page)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py",
> line 214, in list_packages
> data = await self.*fetch_package_metadata(name, latest_version, self.base_url)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\async_lru_*init**.py",
> line 218, in **call**
> return await asyncio.shield(fut)
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py",
> line 36, in _fetch_package_metadata
> response = await http_client.fetch(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\simple_httpclient.py",
> line 340, in run
> stream = await self.tcp_client.connect(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpclient.py",
> line 288, in connect
> stream = await stream.start_tls(
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py",
> line 1389, in _do_ssl_handshake
> self.socket.do_handshake()
> File "C:\Users\lee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1342, in do_handshake
> self._sslobj.do_handshake()
> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host [E 2023-06-21 18:24:09.255
> ServerApp] {
> "Host": "localhost:8888",
> "Accept": "*/*",
> "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
> "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
> }

Comment: Your simple code example isn't enough. In other words, it may or may not be too simple? (Also looks like it has a syntax error and so it isn't even reproducible. Please try running what you have pasted, as-is.)From what I see there you aren't specifying handling of the output in relation to the how ipywidgets now works. You may be using older example and haven't updated to the current best practices in the documentation? Hint look for use of `widgets.Output()` in the documentation and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-output-in-log-rather-than-cell/13419/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: Not sure what you mean about syntax errors.  The code example was taken directly from ipywidgets docs as tab example.  https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html#tabs

Also, have had additional ZMQstream errors with both notebook and  lab.  Believe it to be related to older ver of ipykernel which install didn’t update.

Comment: By 'syntax error', I meant this line won't run when I paste your code as it appears here in Jupyter: `tab = widgets.Tab() tab.children = children`.  It gives 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'. Maybe it was a pasting error? Either way it is why I say it is always best to actually run your own posted code block so you are conveying what you are really using.

Comment: About your actual issue ... Jupyter now is a much different beast than older stuff. You should probably read these two posts [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyter-notebook-6-5-0-release-candidate-4c229c6dab55) & [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-0-is-here-388d05e03442). The first will give you an overview of the ecosystem underlying things now so that you'll see it is more likely if you don't update everything, it will break and/or interfere. If that is going to cause you problems with your older stuff, I'd suggest making a virtual environment and installing the new stuff ....

Comment: <continued> there. Or alternatively, switch to installing [the Ancaconda Distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/index.html), and read about getting started with that and make a new environment, activate that environment and update to JupyterLab 4 there and then install ipywidgets using conda in the terminal in that same environment: `conda install -c anaconda ipywidgets`.